# how to save to bash_profile using nano editor

Tags: macos

I open bash_profile using the command

```
nano .bash_profile
```

To save, I tried ctlr + x, then Y.

then I open the file again, changes are not there?

what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Nano <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>  exits the program. If you want to save changes to a file you've edited do:

> <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd> then  <kbd>Enter</kbd> followed by
>   <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

This will overwrite the previous file with the changes and then exit.